# Detect the voice of multiple person speaking

Tags: android, fft, speech-recognition, media-player, android-audiorecord

I want to create an Android application that, when I use my own TTS (Text-to-Speech) function to speak, listens to the surrounding sounds and triggers an event when it detects someone else speaking. My idea is to use FFT to compare the original TTS audio with external user voices. Is there any method to achieve this?

I have tried to use the below logic to compare the FFT genrate by JTransforms

```
private fun calculateCosineSimilarity(vector1: DoubleArray, vector2: DoubleArray): Double {
        if(vector1.size != vector2.size){
            return 0.0
        }

        var dotProduct = 0.0
        var norm1 = 0.0
        var norm2 = 0.0
        var i = 0
        while (i < vector1.size) {
            dotProduct += vector1[i] * vector2[i] + vector1[i + 1] * vector2[i + 1]
            norm1 += Math.pow(vector1[i], 2.0) + Math.pow(vector1[i + 1], 2.0)
            norm2 += Math.pow(vector2[i], 2.0) + Math.pow(vector2[i + 1], 2.0)
            i += 2
        }
        return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(norm1) * Math.sqrt(norm2))
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure but a low level stt + tts software could require millions of lines of code. This cannot be done in view lines of Java code. However you could use Google APIs and let Google do the work. https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries

Comment: Also note modern STT perhaps doesn't use FFT at all but AI instead.

Comment: A hard way to do this on FFT only might not be possible. You can also try PCA after FFT and then you can somehow do unsupervised clustering, here you might see big different clusters that separate women from men (high pitch from low pitch) and so on... As others say, there should be some trained models for this already